# expectation of estimators

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this question to answer about expectation but I only understand how to get the estimator from a table and was wondering if anyone knew the answer/knew how to explain this:
Independent random variables
X
1
and
X
2
both come from a population with mean
μ
and variance
σ^2
. Three estimators for the parameter
μ
are as follows:

μ1=
2/3
X
1
+
1/3
X
2
,

μ2=
1/3
X
1
+
3/4
X
2
,

μ3=
1/2
X
1
+
1/2
X
2

Calculate the expectation and the variance of each estimator. State which estimator is preferable to use and why.

Answer (score 2):

So you are given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables both having mean $E[X_i]=\mu$ and variance $\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$ for $i=1,2$. To calculate the expectation and variance of a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (which is what the $\mu_i$'s are) then you must use some basic properties of the expectation and variance (the latter is the one requiring independence)

- The linearity of the expectation, i.e. $E[aX+bY]=a\cdot E[X]+b\cdot E[Y]$ for integrable random variables $X$ and $Y$ and real numbers $a,b$.
- If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then 
  $$
  \mathrm{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\mathrm{Var}(X)+b^2\mathrm{Var}(Y)
  $$
  for any choice of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

What do you think are preferable properties of an estimator in terms of its mean and variance?

Comment: I just have a quick question. Will this come out with an actual numerical answer or just a formula in terms of sigma^2 ?

Comment: @Bubblez775: The mean will be expressions involving $\mu$ and the variance will be expressions involving $\sigma^2$.